# how to get rid of \' from queried string which produced \' in string instead of '

Tags: json, string, sequelize.js

I queried using Sequelize which produces result ONTARIO\'S INSTEAD OF ONTARIO'S. I want of inject it into a JSON String where I want it to be ONTARIO'S INSTEAD OF ONTARIO\'S. I used this is achieve the results.

```
var text = ("ONTARIO\'S").replace(/\'/g,"'");
```

However this doesn't give me desired result. Can some body help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good probability that you are confusing the way the object notion prints when inspecting with the way it would appear if using the data within the object.

Have you tried using the JSON string data to print? They may not be visible when using them in your UI for example, but may be present when inspecting the JSON object. Try using the strings and see for example if using them in your UI, if the escaped single quotes will persist.